# In typescript, promisify converts fs.stat to ts error 2349

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am a typescript beginner, I have encountered some typescript warnings when using promisify to convert fs.stas.

```
 const stat: (
  pathname: string
) => Promise<fs.Stats | NodeJS.ErrnoException> = util.promisify(fs.stat);
```

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Stats' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` look like?

The following works for me:

```
import fs from "fs";
import util from "util";

const stat: (pathname: string) => Promise<fs.Stats> = util.promisify(fs.stat);
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^11.11.8",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000"
  }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't specify the type of error `stat` throws in the type of the promise. So instead of `Promise<fs.Stats | NodeJS.ErrnoException>`, you should just do `Promise<fs.Stats>`